# Markdown handles inline bold text (within a word) incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

When I bold text inline like
**strong**text
it gets parsed as italics instead of either bold or nothing.

I created the above with the following line:

```
**strong**text
```

As I understand it, inline Markdown is disabled here, so this text should really be ignored.

Comment: Encountered this today, was a fair bit frustrating! While there is a workaround in the answers below, it's rather annoying.

Comment: This is a feature request now: [Add the ability to add emphasis to part of a word in Markdown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116990/add-the-ability-to-add-emphasis-to-part-of-a-word-in-markdown).

Comment: This is especially annoying in Japanese (and other languages that don't use spaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is point 2. in [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229236/115866) and will work correctly after the next build.

Answer (score 10):

For questions and answers (but not comments) there is a workaround with <b> and <i> tags:

```
<b>strong</b>t<i>ext</i>
```

Produces:

> **strong**t*ext*

Comment: This workaround is not equivalent. The equivalent workaround would be <strong>strong</strong>t<em>ext</em>. They do not work in comments — which is a shame.

Answer (score 6):

This would be useful when explaining acronyms, such as **H**yper**t**ext **T**ransfer **P**rotocol.

(Adding as answer since the workaround doesn't work in comments)

Comment: HTTP is not an acronym ;-) but your point is good.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco: Of course HTTP is an acronym, don't be daft!

Comment: @Noldorin Actually HTTP is an initialism. Acronyms have to be pronouncable. http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2012/05/the-difference-between-an-acronym-and-an-initialism/

Comment: @DavidGiven: Yeah, I'm aware of that now, but it's certainly not universally accepted that acronyms don't refer to initialisms. Traditionally, the term *acronym* was used by most to refer to both strict acronyms (as many would call them now) and initialisms... it's a point of contention among modern linguists, I've learnt.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I've seen with ***text*** being bold & italics is in comments. There doesn't seem to be a problem otherwise.

With the word 'text' above, I used 3 asterisks (*) surrounding the word.

***Here***, I have used the font menu options above the editor.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
I see what you're saying. **strong**text will not bold 'strong'. Three asterisks on either side will bold, but then you are left with hanging (*) on either side. The parser does appear to have an inner *Twilight Zone* when it comes to this markdown.

Comment: I used the "B" button to generate the bold markup. In either case something is wrong - either the button or the parser.

Comment: The problem isn't text being bold and italics, it's text trying to be bold inline, but ending up italic. Basically, emphasizing a single part of a word. In the question, for example, the goal would be "strongtext", with "strong" being bold. Instead we get "*strong*text" with strong being italic.

Comment: oh...ok, I see what you're saying.

Comment: If you put a space after what your trying to bold then you will be fine

Comment: This would be useful when explaining acronyms, such as <b>H</b>yper<b>t</b>ext <b>T</b>ransfer <b>P</b>rotocol.

Comment: @Mech — Your point is good, although HTTP is not an acronym ;-)