# Why do I have to hack to get a bold letter in a word?

Tags: support, status-completed, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown handles inline bold text (within a word) incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51404/markdown-handles-inline-bold-text-within-a-word-incorrectly)

See here:

If I want to write `Hello` but only bold the `H` I can try:

> **H**ello

Well that is weird....
What I typed was `**H**ello`. That **should** have worked.

It does work when I use a UTF-8 Hack however:

> **H**​ello

Looks the same: `**H**​ello` but somehow it shows differently.

What I am using is called a [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm). The problem is, why do I have to go through so much trouble just to make **one letter** in a word bold?

This affects times where people have to make answers like over [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/203). Where the OP is trying to emphasize certain beginning of words.

Can this be fixed? As shown it is as easy as a UTF-8 Hack in the markdown.

Comment: @YiJiang'sProble_ yes, but i am proposing a solution.

Comment: As it is possible to escape the asterisk, who wants to write `**He**llo` could still do it by writing `\*\*H\*\*ello`. I don't see in which cases highlighting the first letter would be done when the user doesn't want that.

Comment: @kiamlaluno i dont want to write \*\*H\*\*ello

Comment: I understood that; I am just saying that who wants to write `**H**ello` could still do it. My comment was also to say that I doubt we would have users asking why they get a bold _H_ when they wanted to write `**H**ello`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno ha, that is true ^_^

Comment: As an aside, [the "official" Markdown claims](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#em): "*Emphasis can be used in the middle of a word: `un*frigging*believable`"*

Comment: Did you really just post two consecutive duplicate posts on the same topic? LEARN 2 <b>!

Comment: @Jeff -- how is that **not** a bug?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The problem is, why do I have to go through so much trouble just to make **one letter** in a word bold?

Because the [`StrictBoldItalic` setting](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/browse/MarkdownSharp/Markdown.cs#125) is set to true in Stack Exchange's Markdown parser, an intentional deviation from the Markdown specification. This is very much [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), presumably stemming from concerns about the characters used to indicate bold and emphasis (particularly underscores) being misinterpreted in the post.

Note that this has [since been improved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works) to allow for the use of asterisks (but not underscores, for the reasons mentioned above) for intra-word emphasis, so your mentioned use case will now work in posts/edits going forward, as well as comments.

Comment: As stated on the other answer. Why does it allow for italics then?

Comment: Odd, @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA. But I doubt it's *allowing* italics, but it's merely failing? Just `*E*mphasis` does not work either.

Comment: Because you've included the pair of asterisks, you've created a non-word boundary that the regular expression considers valid for the purposes of strict italics.

Comment: @Arjan see the OP. the `*H*` is italics

Comment: @TimStone is that why the `ZERO WIDTH SPACE` works then?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Actually, the `H` is in italics, the non-word asterisks are outside of the italics (which is why it happens).

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA A zero-width space is a non-word character.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - because ZERO WIDTH SPACE is treated as a word boundary. It is a space after all.

Comment: @Scrooge I guess... but with **zero-width** lol

Comment: I know, @aman, but I feel it's *wrongly* taking a single asterisk from the two you typed (rather than taking just one *on purpose*). When you just *type* one, the parser is ignoring it too.

Comment: @Arjan Exactly. The problem of course is that the parser can't know your intentions, so when bold doesn't succeed it just blissfully moves on to try italics, which circumstantially work.

Comment: @Arjan and the spin off: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116990/155556 ...

Comment: @AMan​AboutAPlanInPanama, zero width space also work as a boundary in, for example, `@mentions`... ;-) (*What, only now, while starting to type it backwards after the first `@amanU+200B`, I realized it's a palindrome!*)

Comment: @Arjan hehe why yes I am a palindrome ^_^ ‮

Answer (score 7):

The characters used for formatting are also often used in their "normal" meaning, for example in "2*6 = 3*4" or "some_variable_name". You end up with a lot of unintended formatting if you don't restrict where those characters have special meaning.

If you want an easy way to format part of a word, you can use the according HTML tags, like `<b>H</b>ello`.

Comment: Then **why** would the text become italics. your theory makes no sense....

Comment: @aman: That looks like a bug.

Comment: Primo, such cases would be rare, and **escaping** would be there for them.

Comment: Secundo, <b>H</b>ello does not work in comments, neither <strong>B</strong>onjour, neither Good <i>b</i>ye, neither <em>T</em>schüß. Which is a shame.

Comment: Tertio, in answers the equivalent HTML for **H**ello is <strong>H</strong>Hello, not <b>H</b>ello.