# Add the ability to add emphasis to part of a word in markdown

Tags: feature-request, markdown, posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WMD unable to render markup inside words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words)

This question is a direct roll off of this one: [Why do I have to hack to get a bold letter in a word?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116986/155556)

Basically in a post like [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/203) it is useful to have the ability to emphasize (with bolding or something else) part of a word (or words) without having to hack it.

Can we add this feature?

Comment: @Arjan what do you mean?

Comment: I wonder if a screen reader would still just see the whole word `Cahanei`, or two words `C` and `ahanei`. If it's the latter, then reading such text might be messy. But I did *some* testing, and a Mac's text-to-speech does not seem to be bothered by emphasis within a word. Like an emphasized W in `<strong>W</strong>orld` does not make it say `Double-U orld`, while a Unicode U+200B zero width space like in `**W** U+200B orld` does make it fail. For that, I support this feature request. (Unless it might make the formatting of many existing posts fail.)

Comment: @random -- how is this a duplicate? this is a feature-request, **not** a bug report.

Comment: The answer is telling you why it won't be a status-completed

Comment: @random #1) what answer?  #2) that still does not mean that this is a duplicate. let it get rejected.

Comment: The example un*frigging*believable in [the official Markdown doc](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#em) is broken here — broken in comments **and** broken in answers.

Comment: Voting to reopen as I don't agree with closing a feature request as a duplicate of bug reports.