# Bold/italics inside link uses too many *'s

Tags: bug, markdown

Consider a post like this:

```
It's called a [Horizontal Rule][1]...

  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/hr
```

---

If I wanted to italicise the *H* and *R*, I'd change that to:

```
It's called a [*H*orizontal *R*ule][1]...
```

---

But the link displays like this:

It's called a [*H*orizontal *R*ule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/hr)...

---

Doubling the `*`'s should make it bold, like this:

```
It's called a [**H**orizontal **R**ule][1]...
```

---

But instead, it *finally* makes it italics, and keeps the bold's `*`'s:

It's called a [**H**orizontal **R**ule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/hr)...

---

Figuring bold would just need an extra set of `*`'s, I tried:

```
It's called a [***H***orizontal ***R***ule][1]...
```

---

This time, it bolds, but with extra `*`'s displaying in the output:

It's called a [***H***orizontal ***R***ule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/hr)...

---

Finally, we can get bold *and* italic:

```
It's called a [****H****orizontal ****R****ule][1]...
```

---

But this time the extra `*`'s go even stranger:

It's called a [****H****orizontal ****R****ule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/hr)...

---

I guess this must be a bug...

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Did you like my ironic use of `<hr>`'s?</sub>

Comment: `<b>H</b>orizontal <b>R</b>ule` works (at least in answers and questions, not sure about comments).

Comment: It's called a [<b>H</b>orizontal <i>R</i>ule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/hr). @DanielFischer It doesn't. :)

Comment: Here's the [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116990/add-the-ability-to-add-emphasis-to-part-of-a-word-in-markdown) to fix this (please vote to reopen if you can).

Comment: I just noticed this happens within code chunks as well: `*italics*`. Except it doesn't work no matter how many asterisks you put in there...