# How do I make part of a word bold using Markdown?

Tags: support, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown handles inline bold text (within a word) incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51404/markdown-handles-inline-bold-text-within-a-word-incorrectly)

I'm trying to use the following Markdown to make just the "Overflow" part of "StackOverflow Meta" bolded:

```
Stack**Overflow** Meta
```

But it creates the following instead:

> Stack**Overflow** Meta

Why?

Comment: Stack **Overflow** , give a space after `Stack` word

Comment: @Lucifer: I do not want that space, I want them stay together.

Comment: `Stack<b>Overflow</b>` will work in a question/answer.

Comment: While this is a general problem (covered by KennyTM's link), note the name of the site, and by how it should be referred, is "[Stack Overflow](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance)", not "StackOverflow" regardless of how you format "Overflow".

Comment: This problem doesn't appear anymore

Answer (score 20):

Use HTML. <del>Markdown requires a space before the `**`</del>.

> Stack**Overflow**
>
> ```
> Stack<b>Overflow</b>
> ```

***E****d****i****t*: just to update, as [Markdown handles inline bold text (within a word) incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51404/markdown-handles-inline-bold-text-within-a-word-incorrectly) has been fixed in 2014, OP's original code works now, no workaround needed:

> Stack**Overflow**
>
> ```
> Stack**Overflow**
> ```

---

Alternatively you could abuse Unicode

- 
- Stack

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use zero-width space.

> Stack​**Overflow**

Zero-width space doesn't work in comment, though.

Comment: What's Zero-width space?

Comment: Just a Unicode character - it is space, but you won't see the space. You can hit edit on my post and try using arrow to navigate around the text: At the character `k`, you will need to press arrow 2 times to get to `*` of the bold formatting. This is 90% joke/troll and 10% answer.

Comment: I tested before - doesn't work in comment: Stack​**Overflow**. You can confirm by copy, paste this comment into a text editor and navigate around.

Comment: Copy the above text to http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/ and convert you'll see a 0x200B between the 2 words. That's [Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space

Comment: It may not work in SO, but it _does_ work on GitHub.

Answer (score -3):

Well,you need to do like this:
`Stack **Overflow**`

OUTPUT:

Stack **Overflow**

Comment: I think the OP does not want any space between Stack and Overflow.