# Has MarkdownSharp considered East Asian Scripts always have intra-word emphasis?

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

In the post below, Jeff Atwood claimed the MarkdownSharp has changed Markdown rules to disable intra-word emphasis like "the_file_name" or "file_one and file_two".
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/responsible-open-source-code-parenting.html

As a result, the two components at both ends of the regular expressions, only match non-word character. That just what `\W` means:
https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/browse/MarkdownSharp/Markdown.cs#1357

Of course, Pagedown also do the same.

However, **in East Asian Scripts, any emphasises are always "intra-word"**! For example, this line with Markdown notations meant to emphasis two words, "北京" and "上海", that only are separated by the "和":

```
**北京**和**上海**是直辖市。
```

It's very common uses in Chinese. But now, if we want get the "intra-word emphasis" effect,

> **北京**和**上海**是直辖市。

we would have writing like this:

```
<strong>北京</strong>和<strong>上海</strong>是直辖市。
```

So, we have revised the searched regular expressions in MarkdownSharp and Pagedown to (C#):

```
([\W_]|\u4e00-\u9fff|^) (\*\*|__) (?=\S) ([^\r]*?\S[\*_]*) \2 (?=[\W_]|\u4e00-\u9fff|$)
```

and (JavaScript)

```
/([\W_]|\u4e00-\u9fff|^)(\*\*|__)(?=\S)([^\r]*?\S[\*_]*)\2(?=[\W_]|\u4e00-\u9fff|$)/g
```

the replaced patterns to (both server-side and client-side):

```
$1<em>$3</em>
```

---

截止2013年5月16日，下面的格式在图灵社区会原样不变：

```
*_北京_*和*_上海_*是直辖市。_*北京*_和_*上海*_是直辖市。
```

但应该显示为（与StackOverflow一致的）：

*_北京_*和*_上海_*是直辖市。_*北京*_和_*上海*_是直辖市。

---

### 关于杨帆提出的两个问题的疑惑

2013年5月27日，杨帆提到以下文本中的“**站点**”在图灵社区曾经可以显示为粗体：

> 由Web**站点**构成

如上所示，Stack Overflow网页展示的“**站点**”不是粗体（客户端预览也不是）——这倒没关系——关键是，据温谦老师说：

> (图灵社区)现在禁止（词内强调）时，使用的正则表达式（是）："([^A-Za-z0-9]|*|^) (*|*) (?=\S) ([^\r*_]*?\S) \2 ([^A-Za-z0-9]|_|$)"
>   ——出处：http://www.ituring.com.cn/article/38840#reply-19633

这个正则表达式要求匹配[^A-Za-z0-9]，所以杨帆说的“**站点**”曾经可以显示为粗体的情况不可能出现！因为“Web”中的“b”不会与这个组件匹配，双星号也就不会被替换成`<strong>`标签。这是一个疑惑。

2013年4月23日，杨帆还提到以下文本中的Y、A、C、C在图灵社区预览不正确，但结果正确！

> 顺便说一下“yacc”这个名字的由来是**Y**et **A**nother **C**ompiler **C**ompiler的缩写。

Stack Overflow禁用这种“词内强调”，图灵社区好像从一开始都在遵照这个“惯例”吧？如果是，怎么会出现“**结果正确**”这种违反惯例的情况呢？这是第二个疑惑。

**2013-05-27 pm16:34 李松峰**

Comment: ’Tisn’t really a bug if you’re not expecting Chinese text — like on Stack Overflow. Or is this just a bug report for the library?

Comment: Yes, it isn't a bug.

Comment: instead of `<strong></strong>` you could just use `<b></b>` which saves 10 letters.

Comment: @rynah It is an issue on some of the other SE sites, like the Japanese and Chinese sites.  (Unsure if it also applies to Russian or other non-latin alphabet language sites.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51404/markdown-handles-inline-bold-text-within-a-word-incorrectly and http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/120/issues-with-bolding

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we (finally) have considered this. For more info see [Markdown change: Intra-word emphasis now works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works).

I've also updated the public repositories today: [PageDown change](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/detail?r=50c01599393cc141ba2ccbf985eb8fd522cb1825), [MarkdownSharp change](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=0f589032937d75598a99e33b5195caf016545bdd).